# Ws-Trust authentication which has been deprecated and no longer supported in your environment. Please use oAuth2.0 authentication

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm, crm, webapi

In Current Project i am using this syntax to retrieve data from Dynamic CRM:

```cs
using (OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, null, _crmCredentials, null)
{
    // Creating IOrganizationService object to access organization services
    IOrganizationService service = serviceProxy;
    EntityCollection retrieveAccountGuid = service.RetrieveMultiple(QueryOptions);

    return retrieveAccountGuid;
}
```

Any one please help me what changes i need to do?

I have Read this article but how to replace `IOrganizationService` in code?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-office365-deprecation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When possible, please do not include images of code. Instead just include a code block in your post.

Comment: Sure Will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CrmServiceClient` is the class we can use to connect to Dynamics 365 in .NET. It supports multiple authentication scenarios. For server-to-server communications on Azure and the Power Platform working with app registrations is the recommended approach.

App registrations accessing Dynamics/Dataverse need to be added as application users and must be assigned an appropriate security role. See also [Register an app with Azure Active Directory - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory).

`CrmServiceClient` implements the `IOrganizationService` interface, so the majority of your code should work just the same way. Just replace the instantation of the `OrganizationServiceProxy` by something like this:

```cs
private void Test(Uri dataverseUrl, Guid clientId, string clientSecret, string tokenCachePath)
{
    using (var client = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(dataverseUrl, clientId.ToString("D"), clientSecret, false, tokenCachePath))
    {
        Perform(client);
    }
}

private void Perform(IOrganizationService organizationService)
{

}
```

`CrmServiceClient` can be found in NuGet package `Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly`.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply but can i change in existing OrganizationServiceProxy  ? Any idea?

Comment: No, OrganizationServiceProxy is tied to WS-Trust and is deprecated. You will need to replace that piece of code.

Comment: CrmServiceClient cv = new CrmServiceClient(con);
                IOrganizationService _orgService = (IOrganizationService)cv.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? OrganizationService)cv.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)cv.OrganizationServiceProxy;
EntityCollection retrieveAccountGuid = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryOptions); Using this syntax i am getting null value in OrganizationServiceProxy any idea?

Comment: This is because the `CrmServiceClient` instance you created does not support `OrganizationServiceProxy`. You do not need the proxy anyway, because `CrmServiceClient` implements `IOrganizationService` already. Just use the client instead of the proxy.

Comment: Nice. Maybe you could flag this post as an answer?

Comment: It seems to work fine if you use the App ID AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d; RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97 but when I try to use my own App Registration as outlined in the instructions, I get a null object reference error.

Comment: Which .NET Framework you are using?

Answer (score 2):

```
public CrmServiceClient devuelve_Servicio()
    {           
        CrmServiceClient svc = null;

        
        string ConnectionString = "AuthType = OAuth; " +
              "Username = ;" +
              "Password = ; " +
              "Url = https://.crm.dynamics.com;" +
              "AppId=;" +
              "RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;" +
              "LoginPrompt=Auto";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        try
        {
            
            CrmServiceClient svc = new CrmServiceClient(ConnectionString);
            if (svc != null)
            {

                this.strErrMsg  = "Error en la conexión!!!" + "LastError: " + svc.LastCrmError.ToString();
               
               }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            this.strErrMsg = ex.Message;
        }
        return svc;
    }
}
```

Comment: did microsoft change anything? that old code of organization proxy working for me now. Any update?